# Account Name not displaying

Tags: soql, formula-field, administration, account

I created this formula field to display a hyperlink to the direct parent account on whatever record a user is viewing. For some reason the link displays the account Id number and not the actual name of the account.

Formula Field:

```
IF(
   NOT(ISBLANK(Parent_Account__c)), 
   HYPERLINK("/" & Parent_Account__c, Parent_Account__c, '_self'), ''
)
```

Comment: you should use PArent_Account.Name

Answer (score 3):

The [`HYPERLINK()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) formula function accepts both a URL and a display name for the link. You're constructing both using the `Parent_Account__c` field, which is the *relationship field*:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Parent_Account__c, Parent_Account__c, '_self')
```

The content of a relationship field is always a Salesforce Id. If you'd like to display the name, or any other related field, you need to reference it explicitly:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Parent_Account__c, Parent_Account__r.Name, '_self')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parent_Account__r.Name` should give you the parent account name you're looking for.  Try that in the second parameter of the `HYPERLINK()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula for the HYPERLINK should be some like if you are using the Parent *out of the box* relationship.

```
HYPERLINK("/" &  ParentId , Parent.Name, '_self')
```